# GridView first item not working

Tags: android, gridview

i have a GridView of button, i need to change background and clickable on some button, it works well for all but not the first one :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        Button btn;

        if (convertView == null) {

            btn = new Button(mContext);

            btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(44,44));
            btn.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            }
        else {
            btn = (Button) convertView;
        }



    btn.setId(position);
    bottoni[position] = btn;  
    //abilito o disabilito caselle
    if (mossa == 1){
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C85A17"));
            btn.setClickable(true);
    }
    else {  
    if (statobtn[position] == "A") {
        btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.semi));
        btn.setClickable(true); }
    if (testobtn[position] != "") {
        btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fiorebianco));
        btn.setClickable(false);    }
    }


    btn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position,btn));  


     return btn; 
    }
```

any idea?

i start with 100 button eneabled afer first i need to enable only some buttons related to the button clicked, but the first button is always enebled...

Comment: Can we see the rest of `getView`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and fixed it by removing/modifying GridView.LayoutParams.

Try commenting out the following code:

```
btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(44,44));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. it gave me clues to solve a different problem.

Comment: I had the same problem. How would i keep the comment
' btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(44,44)); ' while solving the problem as i really need this comment in my case

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when I keep my view in a view holder.
To solve this, I try create new view in case position = 0, it work.

In your code, change

`if (convertView == null)`

to

`if (convertView == null || position == 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

GridView may call getView for position 0, so it will have many Button for position 0. But, the last one may be not the one on the screen, so you may be change the wrong Button.

How to solve it?

You can give tags for every Button, then find the right Button on the screen through GridView.findViewByTag().